# Can't access symlinks within webdav folders [using apache 2.2.22] or map drive for explorer [windows]

Tags: apache, ssl, webdav

I am using apache 2.2.22 with debian stable as the server.

I have created a virtual host for a webdav share. I can access all of the symbolic links contained in /webdav via a web browser, just not from a webdav client. If i put documents or proper folders within /webdav i can see them in a client.

Here is my config for the share:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName  mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydoman.com   
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>
    ErrorLog  /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName  mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.key
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/htdocs/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>
    ErrorLog  /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

Alias /webdav /var/www/html/mydomain/htdocs
    <Location /webdav-public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #AllowOverride None
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Permissions for root and webdav folder:
Owner: root, create/delete; Group www-data, access; Other, none

Permissions for the public folder which the symlinks point to:
Owner: myusername, create/delete; Group: www-data, access; Other, Access

Any ideas? Obviously i am trying to learn my way around apache so there is probably a few errors in the above, i welcome any off topic criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it turns out:

```
<Location /webdav-public>
```

A location as above can be a symbolic link. However, symbolic links within the share location are not supported for whatever reason (at least for apache 2.2.22 in the debian stable repo). They do show when accessed by firefox or chrome for me, but not from a webdav client or while mapped in windows explorer (while on the home network, not tested elsewhere).

I had to rearrange my files to suit webdav, which sucks.